# wait for camera reconnect C#

Tags: c#, windows, thread-safety

I am working with the Kinect, and every so often it will shut down mid program, causing all sorts of errors. Since there are no fixes to this issue, I want to set up my program to pause whenever the Kinect does this.

```
public ManikinTrackingManager()
    {
        KinectSensor.GetDefault().IsAvailableChanged += MainWindow_IsAvailableChanged;
    }
    private bool kinnected = true;
    private void MainWindow_IsAvailableChanged(object sender, IsAvailableChangedEventArgs e)
    { 
        if (e.IsAvailable == true)
        {
            SpeechSynthManager.SpeakAsync("Kinect has been found!");
            kinnected = true;
        }
        else
        {
            SpeechSynthManager.SpeakAsync("Your Kinect has been disconnected!");
            SpeechSynthManager.SpeakAsync("Please wait while I try to fix this problem!");

            kinnected = false;
            waitForReconnect();
        }
        SpeechSynthManager.SpeakAsync("CHANGED " + e.IsAvailable.ToString());
    }
```

This is what I have to catch disconnect. However, if I try to use a timer on a loop to wait until the camera is reconnected, by saying

```
void waitForReconnect()
{
     while (kinnected == false)
     {
          Thread.sleep(500);
     }
}
```

However, instead of pausing until the Kinect is reconnected, this code just freezes my whole computer. What else should I try?

Comment: Doesn't the reconnecting fire `IsAvailableChanged` again with `IsAvailable` as true?

Comment: It should, but I'm not sure if the reconnect triggers IsAvailableChanged @stuartd

Comment: @Flotolk, Does `SpeakAsync` return `Task`?

Comment: @Nkosi I don't think so. It's just a function to make the speech synthesizer say the following string

Comment: There is not enough information here. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: @Nkosi this should be all you need to reproduce the problem... and the problem is crystal clear, instead of pausing the program until the camera is reconnected, it freezes the program until I restart it

Comment: @stuartd i tested it with my program and reconnecting the kinect will change and set the `IsAvailable` attribute to true.

Answer (score 0):

UI will freeze because you are executing all your operations in the UI thread. And when you call Thread.Sleep in UI thread, it freezes the UI completely. Usually, it's done in the separate thread.

Even if you want to freeze UI, then you need to update kinnected variable in a separate thread.

Use [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx), [Tasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx) or something similar to execute your operations.

To synchronize threads instead of Thread.Sleep use [ManualResetEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.threading.manualresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx) or other synchronization objects. Avoiding Thread.Sleep is a good practice.

Also, look into async/await.

Comment: I want the UI to freeze, as a lot of things the user does are timed. What I don't like is that the UI stays frozen even after I reconnect the camera

Comment: Depending on how it is implmented events can't fire if the UI thread is blocked. You need to disable the UI programaticly while you wait instead of locking up the UI thread.

Comment: Don't freeze UI ever, don't allow user to do anything, but don't freeze.

Comment: Even if you want to freeze UI, then you need to update kinnected variable in a separate thread.